# Variance of $X-E(X|Y)$

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

A joint probability distribution $f(x,y)=2\mathrm{I}_{(0<x<y<1)}$ is given, and I need to calculate
$$\mathrm{Var}[Y+X-E(X|Y)]$$
I can separate it into
$$\mathrm{Var}[Y]+\mathrm{Var}[X-E(X|Y)]$$ since
$$\mathrm{Cov}(Y,X-E(X|Y))=0$$, but how do I get $\mathrm{Var}[X-E(X|Y)]$?

It seems $E(X|Y)=Y/2$, if that being said, is it okay to simply do like $$\mathrm{Var}[X-E(X|Y)]=\mathrm{Var}(X-Y/2)=\mathrm{Var}(X)+\mathrm{Var}(Y)/4-\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$$
?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Comment: If so, I don't get the intention of the exercise. If Var(X-E(X|Y)) can be obtained by simply converting E(X|Y) into an expression in terms of Y, isn't it okay to calculate Var[Y+X−E(X|Y)] by calculating Var(Y+X-Y/2)= Var(X+Y/2) in the first place, before separating Var[Y+X−E(X|Y)] into Var[Y]+Var[X−E(X|Y)]?

Comment: If okay to solve like Var[Y+X−E(X|Y)]=Var(X+Y/2), I don't know why I am asked to calculate Var[Y+X−E(X|Y)], instead of Var[X−E(X|Y)], since there's no point in using the fact that Cov(Y,X−E(X|Y))=0.